# How do I get the name of a subclass when annotating the method of a parent?

Tags: typescript, typescript-decorator

I wrote a method decorator to log some information about a class. It mostly works as expected but has one issue. I want it to log the name of the effectively running class, but it logs the name of the abstract parent class.

Here is the decorator code:

```js
const logClassName: MethodDecorator = (
  target: any,
  _propertyKey: string,
  _descriptor: PropertyDescriptor,
) => {
  console.log(`class name from decorator: ${target.constructor.name}`);
};
```

The two class definitions, one `abstract` and the second extends the first, thus creating a concrete class

```js
abstract class AbstractClass {
  @logClassName
  logClassName() {
    console.log(`class name from function : ${this.constructor.name}`)
  }
}

class ConcreteClass extends AbstractClass {}
```

And here is the sample execution:

```js
const concrete = new ConcreteClass();
concrete.logClassName();
```

The output:

```
class name from decorator: AbstractClass
class name from function : ConcreteClass
```

I would expect both logs to contain `ConcreteClass`, or at least to contain the same thing.

What I want to know is how to get the decorator log to print the concrete class.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rjw0xd71/) with a working example

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, the issue was that decorators in TypeScript are evaluated once, when the class is defined. This means that when the `@logClassName` decorator is applied to the `AbstractClass` method, it is evaluated with `AbstractClass` as its target.

To capture the effective running class, I had to delay accessing the constructor's name until the method was called. This can be achieved by wrapping the original method with a new function that logs the name of the current instance's constructor:

```js
const logClassName: MethodDecorator = (
  target: any,
  propertyKey: string,
  descriptor: PropertyDescriptor,
) => {
  const originalMethod = descriptor.value;
  
  descriptor.value = function(...args: any[]) {
    console.log(`class name from decorator: ${this.constructor.name}`);
    return originalMethod.apply(this, args);
  }
  
  return descriptor;
};
```

Here's the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w36r1ofb/)